# CSS effect not visible in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

When you hover over an image the surface of the image will become grey and text appears. This effect works in both chrome and safari but when I tried it in Mozilla Firefox, the grey area appears only as a little square box up in the left corner. I can't figure out why, so hopefully someone here can spot the cause of the problem.

This is the CSS that I use. As you can see I've added the moz-transition.

```
span.text-content span {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

span.text-content {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
}

ul.img-list li:hover span.text-content {
  opacity: 1;
}
span.text-content {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 500ms;
  -moz-transition: opacity 500ms;
  -o-transition: opacity 500ms;
  transition: opacity 500ms;
}
```

Comment: Any reason you have 2 `span.text-content` css styles?

Comment: Must have added it by mistake when copy/paste. I've edit it now.

Comment: have you tried using div's?

Comment: What happens when you remove the `-moz-transition:opacity 500ms;` On mine version of FF (the newest) `transition` works with the prefix. and can you add some html code or a fiddle?

Comment: and try to add `opacity: 1 !important;`  to `ul.img-list li:hover span.text-content `

Comment: Nothing happens when I remove it. FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/5az8n4L2/

Comment: @Vinc199789 Nothing at all.

Comment: works in my firefox... try updating. You also STILL have 2 `span.text-content` styles. You should consolidate.

Comment: @Michael When I run in the fiddle in FF it works fine so there has to be a problem on your side

Comment: Works in fiddle it seems. But as soon as I run it local, it does not. Must be some code that's stopping it then.

Comment: Also - you really need to look at standard CSS conventions. You have redundancies everywhere. `.image2` has the same style as `.image3` etc... why not just have one class called `.image` and apply the style to everything? It will also be easier to source out errors

Comment: Been trying some new stuffs and haven't cleaned it up yet.

Comment: For your `span.text-content` rule try changing `display: table;` to `display: inline-block;`

Comment: Only thing that happened with that change was that the text, that appears center of image when hover, appears at the top instead.

Comment: It works for me too on your fiddle [jsfiddle.net/5az8n4L2](http://jsfiddle.net/5az8n4L2). What version of Firefox are you using? Have you cleared your cache?